# How to limit the width and height in UITextView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uitextview

I want to make a UITextView which have a maximum width and a minimum height.Just like chat bubble in "message" App in our iPhone.
I tryed to use **sizeThatFits**.But it didn't give me a wonderful size.

```
NSString *string = @"hello everyone";
_textView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
_textView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16];
_textView.text = string;
[self.view addSubview:_textView];

CGSize size = [string sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16]}];
CGFloat finalWidth = MIN(250, size.width);
CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(finalWidth, MAXFLOAT);
CGSize finalSize = [_textView sizeThatFits:constraintSize];
_textView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, finalSize.width, finalSize.height);
```

I know there are something wrong with my code.So I wonder a good way to limit the width and height in UITextView correctly.
    Thanks

---

some friends tell me to use Autolayout.Then I try to do it.Here is my code

```
   [_textView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *maker){
    maker.right.equalTo(self.mas_left);
    maker.top.equalTo(self.mas_top);
    maker.width.lessThanOrEqualTo(@(250));
    maker.height.greaterThanOrEqualTo(@(40));
}];
```

But it doesn't work unless I use **[_textView sizeToFit]**
Is there anything wrong with my constraints? I want textView adjust itself according to its content!

Comment: Use Autolayout by adding constraints to your UITextView. Magic will happen without writing code. :)

Comment: You should use autolayout!

Answer (score -1):

```
  let minTextViewHeight = CGFloat(33)
  let maxTextViewHeight = CGFloat(70)
  @IBOutlet var textViewHeightConst: NSLayoutConstraint!
     func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {
            //TEXTVIEW HEIGHT INCREASE WHILE TYPING
            var height = ceil(txtViewChat.contentSize.height) // ceil to avoid decimal

            if (height < minTextViewHeight) {  
                height = minTextViewHeight
            }
            if (height > maxTextViewHeight) { 
                height = maxTextViewHeight
            }
            if height != textViewHeightConst.constant { 
                textViewHeightConst.constant = height
              }
        }
```